# Create user with grant privileges on only one database

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

I want to grant ***read/write privileges*** to new user ***only to one*** database, so he can't access other databases.

---

After I created new user with: 
`sudo -u postgres createuser <username>` What privileges this user get?

Is this all I need:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db TO new_user;` to get access to only one database?

What is the best way to do this?

Using PostgreSQL 10

Comment: The user might need additional priviliges on the schema's and other objects in the database. Make sure you have revoked CONNECT privileges from PUBLIC for all the other databases otherwise the new user can connect to those.

Comment: So new user gets privileges to (public)all databases and I need to revoke CONNECT from public. After that user has no rights to connect to any database? 
And then I can GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on my db to user and thats it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `PUBLIC` (everyone) is allowed to connect to all databases. So you'd have to revoke that privilege and hand out `CONNECT` more judiciously.

In addition to that, you'd have to make sure that every user has `CREATE` on all schemas in “his” database and the necessary privileges on all tables, because privileges on the database itself are not enough to access the objects *in* the database.

It could be the simplest solution to use `REASSIGN OWNED` to give the user ownership of all objects in “their” database.